# Ajax Get response data undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to parse the Json string which is returned by the ajax method but it is showing undefined when alerting the lat,long value but when I print the console log the data is displayed correctly there. Can anyone help here on how to parse the GET response data

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/v1.0/tasks/'+document.getElementById("autocomplete").value,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'value' : $(this).val() },
    success : function(data){
    var lat,long;
     data=JSON.stringify(data)
     for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
     lat = data[x].lat;
      alert(lat);
     long = data[x].longi;
     alert (long);
     }

} });
```

API Response:

```
{
  "task": [
    {
      "lat": 41.21555555555555, 
      "longi": -111.99694444444445, 
      "markerText": " Ogden UT 84401"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly remove the call to `JSON.stringify()`. It makes no sense and will cause issues as you're currently attempting to loop over the characters in the JSON string. Secondly, you need to access `data.task`, not just `data`. Try this:

```js
// AJAX response
var data = {
  "task": [{
    "lat": 41.21555555555555,
    "longi": -111.99694444444445,
    "markerText": " Ogden UT 84401"
  }]
}

// in the AJAX success handler:
var lat, long;
data.task.forEach(function(task) {
  lat = task.lat;
  long = task.longi;
  console.log(lat, long);
});
```